# Not able to replace variable values in Azure PowerShell with script arguments to update APIM policies

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, policy

I have defined my code like this:

```
param ($apim_service_name, $apprid, $rg_name, $tid, $url)

<set-url>@($"$url/{(string)context.Variables["insured-id"]}")</set-url>
$apimContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName $rg_name -ServiceName $apim_service_name
Set-AzApiManagementPolicy -Context $apimContext -Format "application/vnd.ms-azure-apim.policy.raw+xml" -ApiId "echo-api" -OperationId "retrieve-resource" -Policy $PolicyStringRead
```

In the pipeline variable I have added variables and used in my pipeline templates
My PowerShell script looks like this:

```
steps:
  - task: AzurePowerShell@5
    displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: FilePath'
      inputs:
         azureSubscription: 'sub-test'
         ScriptPath: 'test-policy.ps1'
         ScriptArguments: '"$(apim_service_name)" "$(apprid)" "$(rg_name)" "$(tid)" -url $(url)'
         azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
```

Defined variables in variables section of the pipeline

Everything is replacing except the "**url**"

Is it the two "$" symbols that is affecting to replace the string?

Can anyone help me on how to update this, because it requires first "$" symbol in order to read the value

Comment: PS will not substitue variable inside a single quote (only double quote).  Use two double quotes to escape single quote :  ScriptArguments: "$apim_service_name $apprid $rg_name $tid -url $url"

Comment: Thanks @jdweng, I came to know that I was using XML format which in turn did not replace powershell script arguments. Now I have replace token in azure devops which can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @jdweng for suggesting the right solution to the user that resolved the issue.

> PS will not substitue variable inside a single quote (only double quote). Use two double quotes to escape single quote : ScriptArguments: "$apim_service_name $apprid $rg_name $tid -url $url"

We can enclose a string in both Single Quotation or the double Quotations but to replace the value in the variable that starts with the dollar sign ($) before sending for the command processing, you have to use only double quotes as given in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.3#double-quoted-strings) of PowerShell Quoting Rules.